# .map not is not a function on empty object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to react. I have set up a reducer with the state as an empty object. But when using the .map() function it doesn't seem to work on the object? Does the .map only work on arrays?

```
export const orders = (state = {}, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case "NEW_ORDER":
      const { new_order } = payload;
      const new_state = { ...state, new_order };
      
      console.log(new_state);
      return new_state;
  }
  
  return state;
}
```

Comment: correct. map() is the method of array, not object.

Comment: .map is only a method for arrays and not objects. If you want to use .map you could do `Object.entries(obj).map(func)` or something like that.

Comment: The map function only works on Javascript array and also return an array as result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no, you can not use `.map()` on an object since it is supposed to be used in an array. By the way, if you are trying to store a list of orders, you should use am array instead, so initialize your state with `[]` and not with `{}`, or with a key that actually contains your orders like `{ orders: [] }` and then add the order you received like `const new_state = { ...state, orders: [...state.orders, new_order] }`.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The map function is part of the Array prototype.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

However, I don't see a map function in the code sample you posted?

If you want to loop over an object though you can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

```
const myObj = {foo: "bar"}
const result = Object.entries(myObj).map(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(key)  // "foo"
  console.log(value)  // "bar"
  return `${key}-${value}`
})
console.log(result) // ["foo-bar"]
```